# How to invert 'if there were' (second conditional)

Tags: conditional-constructions

Suppose I want to invert this sentence:

> **If there were** something that could bring you in the past to make a
> restartable decision, that would be great.

Is it correct to write like this? :

> **Were there something** that ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Were there something that* means the same as *If there were something that*.

The form starting with "were" has more of a literary quality, I think.